Gin indexing in PostgrSQL
Why don't I get response when I am using helping verb in searching with Gin indexing?
SELECT * FROM pg19337
WHERE to_tsquery('english','from')@@ to_tsvector('english', body);

I expect to get the related data, but every time when I use another word like it and , so
It back 0 record

"from" is a stopword, that won't work: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-STOPWORDS

A set containing zero rows is a response.  If your client is set up to pay attention to them, you will also get the notice "NOTICE:  text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored", which neatly explains the issue.

So if there is any way  for searching by stop word
